# How can I detect with php that the user uses an ipad when my user agent doesnt conatin something like that

Tags: php, web, ipad, mobile, detection

Hey I'm trying to detect if I am requesting a php website with an ipad. I know this should be possible with

```
if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'iPad')) {
```

but if I just echo my User agent I get this:

```
Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_4) AppleWebKit/605.1.15(KHTML, like Gecko) Version/13.1.1 Safari/605.1.15
```

I know there are many classes etc. to detect that like mobiledetect.. but they are all using the User agent and mine has no ipad in. So what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use [browscap](https://browscap.org/) to detect.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, as of right now, this is no longer possible.  This is due to Apple making changes to create ["Desktop-Class Browsing with Safari"](https://www.apple.com/newsroom/2019/06/the-new-ipados-powers-unique-experiences-designed-for-ipad/), where, on iPadOS, users are presented with the Desktop version of a website.  There isn't anything in the user agent anymore that will allow for distinguishing between the iPad and Desktop.

Comment: I hope Apple will reconsider this, as having that information is useful.

Answer (score 0):

Since you understand how to use PHP:

[How to detect iPad Pro as iPad using javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57776001/how-to-detect-ipad-pro-as-ipad-using-javascript)

Here is the Javascript equivalent with a lot of answers. You will have no problem to copy them to PHP.