# How to detect iPad Mini?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ipad-mini

I have a site that goes to mobile when the width is less than 1000. The problem is, when the iPad Mini is horizontal, its width is 1024 -- the same as an iPad. The iPad is capable of running a particular timeline that I have programmed, but the Mini is not -- it crashes. I want to detect when the user has a Mini and force the site to its mobile version in that case.

I looked at this stackoverflow entry: [Detect iPad Mini in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13248493/detect-ipad-mini-in-html5) but it doesn't actually have any code to detect the mini, though I enjoyed this suggested hack:

```
function isIPadMini( var timeToReachTerminalVelocity )
{
    return (timeToReachTerminalVelocity > IPAD_MINI_THRESHOLD);
}
```

Does anyone know how to detect the Mini please?

I'm just using this css code now:

```
@media (max-width: 1000px) {
  .desktop {
      display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you seeking an HTML/CSS-only solution, or are you amenable to solutions leveraging JS?

Comment: @AlexanderNied: I'm amenable to JS -- it's probably the only way to go. Let me know!

Answer (score 1):

This tends to work for me. It checks to see if the user has a cursor or not. You can also use pointer:none. To be fair though, this will get a phone as well. The only completely accurate way is with PHP or JavaScript.

```
@media (pointer: coarse) {
  .desktop {
      display: none;
  }
  .mobile {
      display: block;
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you explain what cursor: coarse means?

Comment: Pointer coarse means the user does not have a fine cursor. I.e that have a trackpad or a touchscreen.

Comment: But that includes the IPad. I don't want to include the iPad. I just want to single out the Mini.

Comment: You may have to sniff the browser header in JS or PHP to be that specific.

Comment: That's what I need help with.

Comment: Found this on another Stack Overflow page. This will detect an iPad and you can show them the CPU intensive content. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2676897/detect-ipad-in-php

Comment: if(stristr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'], 'Mozilla/5.0(iPad;')) {
    // iPad code goes here.
}

Comment: I appreciate your help, but this code just isn't working for me. It doesn't react when I use it on an iPad. In any case, I want to identify the Mini, not the iPad.